# Design UI in IOS, Scrollview

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiscrollview, storyboard

I am trying to develop my first iOS app... Am not familiar with Xcode as well...So I still don't know how to design the iOS app in storyboard to support all screen sizes... My layout contains a view then a scroll view then another view which contains the controlls... the scrolling is working very well... when I am trying to add constraints, am getting a lot of warnings and the result is not as expected... Since as I said b4, am not familiar with the iOS storyboard and constraints, I don't know how to solve the issue... Is anyone can help me?

[image: Warnings- design - output]

[image: This is the design what am trying to achieve]

**UPDATE**

It is working perfectly in iPhone 4s, 5 and 5s.. the problem is only in iPhone 6 and 6 plus...

Comment: share your constraints

Comment: read some storyboard tutorial or watch videos on storyboard. It will help

Comment: @Bhavin hw should i share all constrints?

Comment: i think there is no errors in constraints...and most of the warnings are of ambiguous constraints warning....so why don't you just try update constraints option from resolve autolayout issues

Comment: am sorry, I didnt get u....

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/AutoLayoutConcepts/AutoLayoutConcepts.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010853-CH14-SW1

Comment: From the looks of it some of your constrains are being broken, this may be because for example you gave one of the views a fixed width, but also told it to stretch so it decided to break one of them. Try removing any fixed widths or heights.   Id recommend you use a tableViewController for this type of user interface and you'll get the scrolling feature for free. You should also watch some auto layout tutorials, its not something that is very easy to learn in minutes unfortunately.

Comment: See this tutorial: Beginning Auto Layout Tutorial in iOS: [Part 1](http://www.raywenderlich.com/50317/beginning-auto-layout-tutorial-in-ios-7-part-1) [Part 2](http://www.raywenderlich.com/50319/beginning-auto-layout-tutorial-in-ios-7-part-2). It was very useful when I was starting with iOS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At last I have figured it out myself... So i want to share it here, so it could be helpful for the newbies like me....

For the Banner (top imageview), Its only need 5 constrints...

- Trailing space to superview
- Leading space to superview
- Top space to superview
- Bottom space to imageview equals 4
- Aspect Ratio...

And for the rest of the layout we have to do it as row by row with three steps each...

First add the following constraints to all layouts in the same row...

- Trailing space to
- Leading space to
- Top space to
- Bottom space to

Then add Equal Width and equal Height for the same controls in the same row... ie, Imageview to imageview and label to label etc..

Then as the last step, add aspect ratio to all controls...

Continue these steps in row by row.. then you can achieve like the picture above without any warning or error....

**UPDATE**
**Important:**
Forgot to mention one more thing, The Aspect Ratio constrain to be added to the view inside scrollview...